# Java regex: how to reduce sequence of same character of a unity?

Tags: java, regex

I would like to replace, in a string, each sequence of brackets with a sequence of brackets of length smaller by one.
This is a possible input:

```
String toBeParsed = "src:expr[src:call[src:name[src:name='m']]]]" +        
    "[src:call[src:name[src:operator='.']]]]" +
    "[src:call[src:name[src:name='getDisplayFormat']]]]" +
    "[src:call[src:argument_list='()']]][src:operator='instanceof']]" +
    "[src:name='MathFormat']]";
```

This is the desire output:

```
String result = "src:expr[src:call[src:name[src:name='m']]]" +        
    "[src:call[src:name[src:operator='.']]]" +
    "[src:call[src:name[src:name='getDisplayFormat']]]" +
    "[src:call[src:argument_list='()']][src:operator='instanceof']" +
    "[src:name='MathFormat']";
```

I have tried to do this with Java class, but it stops removing brackets after two loops:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SequenceCutter{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String toBeParsed = "src:expr[src:call[src:name[src:name='m']]]]" + 
            "[src:call[src:name[src:operator='.']]]]" +
            "[src:call[src:name[src:name='getDisplayFormat']]]]" +
            "[src:call[src:argument_list='()']]][src:operator='instanceof']]" +
            "[src:name='MathFormat']]";
        Matcher bracketsMatch;
        int subIndex = 0;
        String oldString;
        do {
            bracketsMatch = Pattern.compile("\\]+").
                matcher(toBeParsed.substring(subIndex));
            if (!bracketsMatch.find())
                break;
            subIndex = bracketsMatch.end();
            String match = bracketsMatch.group();
            oldString = toBeParsed;
            toBeParsed = toBeParsed.substring(0, subIndex)
                .replace(match, match.substring(1)) + toBeParsed.substring(subIndex);
        } while (bracketsMatch.find() && !oldString.equals(toBeParsed));
        System.out.println("Result: " + toBeParsed);
    }
}
```

I suppose I am doing this thing in a really complicated way but I am not able to find another solution.
Thanks to anybody will try to help me.

Comment: Try just [`.replaceAll("(]+)]", "$1")`](https://regex101.com/r/IDXr1q/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to replace any sequence of 2+ `]` symbols with the same sequence minus 1 `]`, you may use

```
String toBeParsed = "src:expr[src:call[src:name[src:name='m']]]]" +        
        "[src:call[src:name[src:operator='.']]]]" +
        "[src:call[src:name[src:name='getDisplayFormat']]]]" +
        "[src:call[src:argument_list='()']]][src:operator='instanceof']]" +
        "[src:name='MathFormat']]";
System.out.println(toBeParsed.replaceAll("(]+)]", "$1"));
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/wsAzXF).

The `"(]+)]"` pattern will match and capture two or more `]` symbols, and will place all but the last one into a capturing group. Then, all but the last will be put back into result with the `$1` backreference.

Comment: I have tried to work with `replaceAll` but doing something forbidden like:
`toBeParsed.replaceAll("(]+)", "$1".substring(1))`.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: `"$1"` is a string literal. It is only filled with the capturing group value when a match is found, by the regex engine.  You should use my code.